# T test when there are different raters? I am not sure if my procedure is correct

Tags: t-test, cross-validation, intraclass-correlation

I have two sets of translated text. The first set contains poor translations, and the second set includes perfect translations. I asked three evaluators to rate each of the translations. My objective here is twofold. First, I aim to demonstrate agreement among the evaluators using an Intraclass Correlation Coefficient (ICC) measurement. Second, I intend to use a T-test to highlight significant differences between the two sets of translations.

I am familiar with how to perform ICC and T-tests. However, I'm uncertain about conducting a T-test when multiple raters are involved. My current thought process is to take the average rating from the three evaluators for each translation, and then use these average ratings to perform the T-test.  The exampple below is my throught process.

Group A - poor translations

Translation 1: Rater 1 : 2, Rater 2 : 3, Rater 3 : 2

Translation 2: Rater 1 : 3, Rater 2 : 4, Rater 3 : 3

Translation 3: Rater 1 : 2, Rater 2 : 2, Rater 3 :  3

Group B - perfect translations

Translation 1: Rater 1 : 8, Rater 2 : 7, Rater 3 : 9
Translation 2: Rater 1 : 9, Rater 2 : 8, Rater 3 : 8
Translation 3: Rater 1 : 7, Rater 2 : 8, Rater 3 : 8
First, we compute the average rating for each Translation in both groups:

Group A

Translation 1: Average = (2+3+2)/3 = 2.33

Translation 2: Average = (3+4+3)/3 = 3.33

Translation 3: Average = (2+2+3)/3 = 2.33

Group B

Translation 1: Average = (8+7+9)/3 = 8

Translation 2: Average = (9+8+8)/3 = 8.33

Translation 3: Average = (7+8+8)/3 = 7.67

Now, I use the t-test to compare the means of the two groups.
from scipy import stats

````
# These are your means for each Translation
groupA_means = [2.33, 3.33, 2.33]
groupB_means = [8, 8.33, 7.67]

t_stat, p_val = stats.ttest_ind(groupA_means, groupB_means)

print('t-statistic:', t_stat)
print('p-value:', p_val)
```
````

Comment: Welcome to CV, Chen.  Might I suggest that instead of asking why some proposed procedure might be "correct," you ask what a good procedure would be?  In that fashion you are more likely to receive constructive answers that address your statistical problem rather than criticism of what or might not be a good procedure.  Regardless, you do need to format your post to help us understand what the lines beneath "Group A" represent: they are very ambiguous.

Comment: @whuberThanks for the comment. i have revised my question so it is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the t-test here is not unreasonable, but it is not the most powerful way to analyze this data.

In this context, what you really have is a repeated measures ANOVA with both a within and between group factor.  As this may be sufficient to direct you to the correct analysis, I will stop here.  If you would like more information on running such an RM-ANOVA, I will be happy to update.

Comment: so in my case, it would be two way repeated ANOVA ? The between subject would be group A and B , within subject would be the different raters

Comment: By my reading of this context, the between subject effects are the treatment and the raters (where the raters could be viewed as a fixed or random factor), and the within subject effects would be the translation and the interaction of translation and treatment.